# map.clearLayers preventing 'click' event in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

This is supposed to be a route chooser for alternative routes. You click on the route and it selects itself.

For couple of days I am trying to get out of "enchanted circle" :), because after days and days of debugging I have found out that map.clearLayers() method is somehow block the "click" event.

Here's the situation: When you click on one of the routes, you get, in this case, alert "Layer clicked". But when you click another route, or even the same route again, the "click" is not working.

All other events, like doubleclick, mouseout, mousein, etc. are working but click don't... Also mouseup, mousedown don't work either, which could probably solve this issue, but - nothing :(

```
            var $li = $(li);
            route.idx = i;
            $li.data('route', route);
            $li.data('routes', routes);
            $li.on('click', function () {
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.siblings('li').removeClass('active');
                $this.addClass('active');
                renderCarOrWalkRoute($this.data('routes'), $this.data('route').idx);
            });
            $alternatives.find('.routes').append($li);
        }

        for (var i = 0; i <= route.idx; i++) {
            alternativeRoute[i] = renderAlternativeRoute($li.data('routes'), i);
        }

        $($alternatives.find('li')[0]).trigger('click');
        UI.resetScrollPosition();

        alternativeRoute[0].on('click',function (e) {
            UI.alert("Layer clicked!");
        });
```

In method **renderCarOrWalkRoute**, there is **map.clearLayers()**, but if I comment that, routes won't be cleared while selecting the other route.

Has anyone ever encountered that "click" is blocked in any way via Leaflet?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't even see `map.clearLayers()` in your sample code

Answer (score 0):

There is no `map.clearLayers()` method on stock Leaflet, either version 0.7.7 or 1.0.0-rc.3.

Once your script encounters that instruction that it cannot execute, some (if not all) of your event listeners may break.

If you have a custom `clearLayers()` function, then you should share the code in your question if you need further support.

Comment: clearLayers: function () {
  this.eachLayer(this.removeLayer, this);
  return this;
 },

 invoke: function (methodName) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1),
      i, layer;

  for (i in this._layers) {
   layer = this._layers[i];

   if (layer[methodName]) {
    layer[methodName].apply(layer, args);
   }
  }

  return this;
 },

Comment: Sorry, for comment like this, but I don't know how to format it better. The above code is what I have found in leaflet-src.js. Thanks!

Comment: The code you show applies to a [**Layer Group**](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup-clearlayers), not to a map.